# Deleting using left join and a table variable

Tags: t-sql, left-join, table-variable

Maybe I'm missing a bracket or something but I'm having a hard time deleting rows from a table variable where I'm left joining and looking for the key I'm joining on. If it has a value, then I get rid of it. The problem is that I can't get the query to parse. Any ideas?

```
declare @MrTemp 
(
    key1 int
   ,key2 int
)

insert into @MrTemp
select key1, key2 from ASourceTable

delete  
from @MrTemp mt
left join ARealTable art on mt.key1 = art.key1 and mt.key2 = art.key2 
where art.key1 is not null and art.key2 is not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE @MrTemp
FROM @MrTemp mt LEFT JOIN ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the alias after the delete but before the from for the table you want to delete from

```
delete art 
from @MrTemp mt left join ARealTable art on 
mt.key1 = art.key1 and mt.key2 = art.key2 
where art.key1 is not null and art.key2 is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete from one table at a time:

to delete from @MrTemp [where there is a matching record in ARealTable]

```
delete mt
from @MrTemp mt left join ARealTable art on mt.key1 = art.key1 and mt.key2 = art.key2 where art.key1 is not null and art.key2 is not nu
```

ll

or.
to delete from ARealTable [again where the record has a corresponding record in ARealTable]

```
delete art
from @MrTemp mt left join ARealTable art on mt.key1 = art.key1 and mt.key2 = art.key2 where art.key1 is not null and art.key2 is not null
```